# How to access a cookie created via Sveltkit cookies from axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, svelte, sveltekit

I've got a Login form with the following action (`login/+page.server.js`):

```
export const actions = {

    default: async ({ request, cookies }) => {

        const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
        
        // validate and create DTO.
        const loginData = loginDTO(data);

        // if errors returned from building the DTO (validation errors) then return the object.
        if (loginData?.errors && !emptyObject(loginData.errors)) {
            return {
                "data": loginData.data,
                "errors": loginData.errors,
            };
        }


        // perform call to log in a user.
        const response = await login(loginData);
        // const response = await loginUser(loginData);
        if (response.success) {
            // save token to a cookie
            cookies.set(
                'token',
                response.res.data.data,
                {
                    path: '/',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 25 * 365,
                    httpOnly: false,
                    secure: false,
                }
            )

            throw redirect(302, '/')
        }

        return {
            "data": loginData.data,
            "errors": response.errors,
        }
    }
}
```

basically this is making a request to the backend authenticating a user an a JWT token is returned. So far so good, the token is returned and using Sveltekit's `cookies` I can successfully set the cookie, when I inspect Chrome's application tab (in dev tools) I can see the cookie there.

[image: dev tools img]

Now, I need to attach the value of the cookie to my requests. I'm using `axios`. To do so I created an interceptor:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

// let Cookies2 = Cookies.noConflict();
export const app = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1",
    timeout: 1000,
    params: {},
    // withCredentials: true,
})
// Request interceptor. Whenever a new request goes out it will be caught
// by the interceptor and whatever code is defined will be executed before continuing its flow.
app.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        
        console.log("here in http middleware...")
        let token = Cookies.get()
        console.log("token: ", token);
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error)
    }
);
```

But I've got a couple issues:

1. I haven't been able to use Sveltekit's `cookies` object, don't know how to import it here.
2. Since the cookie is visible client-side, I decided to install `js-cookie` to access it, but the `log` statement I've got in the interceptor is always coming back empty, meaning that it's not picking up the cookie.

Any idea what's going on? or any other way I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

I could also scrap the whole cookies approach and simply use a `store`, what are the cons and pros of each approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your file is on the frontend, have you tried using native web API? 
eg; let token = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )token=([^;]+)'))[2]

Comment: how do i differentiate between server files and client files in Sveltekit? I mean, other than naming the file `+page.server.js` how can I create a server file? simply add `.server.js` at the end of the file will make it a server file? ie `fileName.server.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I haven't been able to use Sveltekit's `cookies` object, don't know how to import it here.

The `cookies` API is [only exposed to the server part of SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#cookies-and-headers). This is to encourage keeping sensitive data like JWT tokens secret. If you must access this cookie on the client-side, return it from the server `load()` function and access it via the `data` prop on the +page.svelte component like [this example](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#page-data). (However the preferred method is to use that JWT only on the server side,  which should be possible 99% of the time.)

> 2. Since the cookie is visible client-side, I decided to install js-cookie to access it, but the log statement I've got in the interceptor is always coming back empty, meaning that it's not picking up the cookie.

Perhaps the cookie domain is set for `localhost:5173`, but you are trying to access it from a different domain? Like `127.0.0.1:5173` or `127.0.0.1:8080`? I don't think there's enough information to discern what is happening.

- Where is the second code block running, and what is it trying to do?
- What is serving `127.0.0.1:8080`? A different, non-SvelteKit server?
- Why do you need to use axios? (SvelteKit prefers native `fetch()`, and provides a special augmented version on both the server and client. The augmentations include forwarding cookies.)

> any other way I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

It's not clear what your ultimate goal is, but it feels like you could move the logic from the client to the server side.

---

**update:** (Additional explanation based on comments)

SvelteKit [+server routes](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) are well-documented:

- If you add a file `/src/routes/api/+server.js` (with appropriate exports), that api is accessible at `http://localhost:5173/api/`
- After your `login/+page.server.js` successfully sets the JWT cookie, the JWT cookie is *automatically* sent with all requests to `http://localhost:5173/api/` (or any other route).
- You can use that cookie with 3rd party API's by calling the API from the server (for example: `/src/routes/api/+server.js`). Simply add the cookie to the `fetch()` config options. The exact method may vary depending on the API, but it's usually something like adding a header like `Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_TOKEN]`.

Note: [`+server.js` files](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) are different from [`+page.server.js` files](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js).

- They serve different purposes and should export different types of functions.
- SvelteKit routing files all start with `+`, so `fileName.server.js` will not have any effect on routing.

---

**update 2:** How to fetch from +page, +server routes

You should use the special SvelteKit `fetch` from the [`RequestEvent`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-requestevent). Notice `fetch` is part of the input to `load()`:

```
// src/routes/blog/+page.js
export async function load({ fetch, setHeaders }) {
    const url = `https://cms.example.com/articles.json`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}
```

Comment: thanks. So I'm implementing a login page, my idea is to call a `login` function which lives under `src/api/user.js` file, this will call the backend and a token is returned so I want to save this token in a cookie. I do understand that Sveltekit cookies are only accessible via server files, but how can I create `custom` server files? I mean, what if I want `src/api/user.js` to be a server file? how can I achieve this?

Comment: I mean, other than naming the file `+page.server.js` how can I create a server file? simply add `.server.js` at the end of the file will make it a server file? ie `fileName.server.js`. Should all the files with some business logic and API calls be server files?

Comment: @MrCujo: it's still not clear what you are trying to do, but I tried to update my answer with more info that may help. Is the API you wish to call using the token a 3rd party API? An API that is served by SvelteKit? An API that is served locally from a different non-SvelteKit server? I still don't understand why multiple domains are involved (localhost:5173 and 127.0.0.1:8080)

Comment: The API I'm calling using 127.0.0.1:8080 is a Golang binary, it's not a SvelteKit API. I'm trying to implement the login part of my frontend, so I call the backend endpoint (Go API) to login a user and a token is returned. Eventually I'll use this token on all requests and also will check whether there is a token or not to restrict access to certain pages, will use `hooks` for that piece but i'm not there yet

Comment: can i only use REST verbs for +server routes? there are some cases where i can work with that but some others i need more methods

Comment: @MrCujo: +server routes export *HTTP* verbs (not REST verbs). How would you access non verbs? (The verbs determine the HTTP method; not the API route. Kit (API) routes are determined totally by the directory path; not the filename or method names in the file.)

Comment: sorry, my bad, I meant HTTP verbs. This is all very helpful and useful for what I'm working on and I really appreciate you taking the time to explain these things. One last question though: is it fetch (the one provided by sveltekit) only available to be used on client files? I tried using fetch from `login/+page.server.js` by calling `src/api/auth/+server.js` and I'm getting: `Error: Cannot use relative URL (/api/auth) with global fetch`

Comment: @MrCujo: added another update to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for client-side apps like mobile.etc.

Answer (score 3):

If having the baseURL & attaching the JWT is all you need to do, I would recommend you to stick with the native [fetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#fetch-apis) provided by SvelteKit since it provides more features than the normal [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

To create an equavalent "interceptor" in Svelte, you can make use of the [Hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks), to be more specific, the [handleFetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch) hook.

Here is how it works:

- The frontend of the app has stored the jwt in browser session (like what you have done).
- Whenever svelte frontend do fetching, it fetches from the backend of SvelteKit.
- The backend of SvelteKit fetch target location.
- The fetch from backend of SvelteKit triggers handleFetch hook.
- We can modify the fetches inside the handleFetch hook.
- Since we are using SvelteKit fetch, information such as cookies will be passed to backend's hook, that is how you can access the cookie.

Here is the example code in TypeScript:

```js
// src/hooks.server.ts
import type { HandleFetch } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handleFetch = (async ({ request, fetch, event: { cookies } }) => {
    if (request.url.startsWith(API_URL)) {
        request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${cookies.get('token')}`);
    }
    return fetch(request);
}) satisfies HandleFetch;
```

If you want to something like having a baseURL, you could modify the request.url by creating a new request.

```js
import type { HandleFetch } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handleFetch = (async ({ request, fetch }) => {
    const newRequest = new Request('myBaseUrl' + request.url, request);
    return fetch(newRequest);
}) satisfies HandleFetch;
```